# Apex Approval Process Locks on DML Statements

Tags: apex, dml, locking

I have a custom button on a record which is designed to update the record's status. There is a separate process within a different class, which is locking the record.

I need my pageRef to unlock the record, update and then re-lock. I understand that perhaps factoring the pageRef into the existing class is probably best practice, however i would like to do it independently if possible

How would this be written into the update DML?

```
public with sharing class BannerApplicationExtension {

    public String currentRecordID {get;set;}
    public Application__c updateApp {get;set;}
    public Opportunity updateOpp {get;set;}
    public string redirectUrl {get;set;}
    public boolean assessable {get;set;}

    public BannerApplicationExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        currentRecordID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('ID');
        redirectUrl = '/' + currentRecordID;

        updateApp = [SELECT Id,Status__c,Application_Outcome__c,Opportunity__r.id,Opportunity__r.Date_Application_Signed__c,Opportunity__r.Date_eCaf_Signed__c,Opportunity__r.stagename
                FROM Application__c WHERE id = :currentRecordID LIMIT 1];
        updateOpp = [SELECT Id,stagename,Active_Application__r.id,Lost_Reason__c
                FROM Opportunity WHERE Active_Application__r.id = :currentRecordID LIMIT 1];
    }

public PageReference approve() {
        try {updateApp.Status__c = 'Assessed';updateApp.Application_Outcome__c = 'Approved';updateopp.stagename = 'Won';
            update updateApp;
            update updateOpp;
        } catch(System.Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error updating Application.'+e.getMessage()));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT - Snippet from another class which is locking record initially...

```
public static string submitApplication(String applicationId)
    {
        Application__c app = new Application__c();
        app.Id = applicationId;
        app.Status__c = 'Submitted';
        update app;
        Approval.lock(applicationId);
        return 'Success';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Approval`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm#!) class has methods for locking and unlocking a record:

```
public PageReference approve() {    
    try {
        if(Approval.unlock(updateApp).isSuccess()){
            updateApp.Status__c = 'Assessed';updateApp.Application_Outcome__c = 'Approved';updateopp.stagename = 'Won';
            update updateApp;
            update updateOpp;
            Approval.lock(updateApp);
        }
    } catch(System.Exception e) {
             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error updating Application.'+e.getMessage()));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that you'll need to enable Apex locking/unlocking in your Setup, I believe it is under "Apex Settings."

Comment: Thanks Brian, makes sense to me. However, there seems to be a syntax error somewhere "missing } at catch"

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh Should be fixed

Comment: Hi Brian, unfortunately after some testing it doesn't seem to work. I have added a snippet of the class which is locking the record initially. I have also removed the Approval.lock(updateApp); to see if the record was unlocking at all, it wasn't.

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh Is the unlock call returning an error?

Comment: Hi Brian, no error, however. I think it may be profile related, does the Approval Class take object access into consideration? (modify all etc.)

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh Since it's a DML statement it might if your class is marked as `with sharing`, but I would expect it to show that in the `Approval.UnlockResult.getErrors()` array.  Have you tried running the method in Execute Anonymous or just on its own without any other logic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66367/discussion-between-themikeyboosh-and-illusivebrian).